# JSON RPC api or steps to get ETH transaction on particular address

Tags: php, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am using php. I want to get all deposit transaction by user on it's ETH address. I am using "geth" client. I am not able to get any json rpc api for get transaction. As per search on internet I have tried "eth_newFilter", "eth_getFilterChanges", "eth_getFilterLogs".
I have set below parameters for "eth_newFilter"

```
 array(
        'jsonrpc'=>'2.0',
        'method'=>'eth_newFilter',
        'params'=>array(array("fromBlock"=> "0x0",
          "toBlock"=> "latest",'address'=>'0x14e15d73db916e14fdb91de38da2c59181876200',
'topics'=>[])),
        'id'=>time()
    );
```

in response I am getting id and I am using that id in "eth_getFilterChanges", "eth_getFilterLogs" but both returns empty result.

can anyone help about how to get list of transactions on particular address?